# Неправильно определяет ошибку

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

Добрый день, делаю запрос к БД, получаю результат и пытаюсь найти максимальное и минимальное значение в таблице, но не могу понять почему отладчик выдает подобную ошибку

> System.InvalidCastException: Invalid cast from 'DateTime' to 'Double'

Вот код

```
        private void ValueMinMax(Type ColumnsType,int i)
    {
        if (ColumnsType == typeof(int) || ColumnsType == typeof(Int16) || ColumnsType == typeof(Int64) || ColumnsType == typeof(float) ||
            ColumnsType == typeof(long) || ColumnsType == typeof(decimal) || ColumnsType == typeof(byte) || ColumnsType == typeof(double))
        {
            double a = 0;
            for (int x = 0; x <= Component.dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; x++)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (Component.dataGridView1[x, i].Value != DBNull.Value)
                    {
                        a = Convert.ToDouble(Component.dataGridView1[x, i].Value);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception Error)
                {
                   return;
                }
                    if (a > ValueMetaData.MaxValue)
                    {
                        ValueMetaData.MaxValue = a;
                    }
                    if (a < ValueMetaData.MinValue)
                    {
                        ValueMetaData.MinValue = a;
                    }
            }
        }
        Component.textBox7.Text = ValueMetaData.MaxValue.ToString();
        Component.textBox8.Text = ValueMetaData.MinValue.ToString();
```

в оператор if не попадает тип DateTime (проверял через отладчик)плюс все значения сбойное колонки (с индексом последовательности 1) корректны и содержат тип Int32

PS.
Последовательность типов в таблице

> DateTime;Int32;Int32;String;String;DateTime;String;String;String;Boolean;String;String;String;String;String;

Comment: при каких значения `i`,`x` и каком значении `Component.dataGridView1[x, i].Value` падает?

Comment: при  i = 1 x = 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В индексатор DataGridView сначала передается columnIndex, а потом rowIndex. Соответственно, программа пытается привести значение 1-ой строки 0-го столбца (тип DateTime) к Double. Для того, чтобы решить вашу проблему нужно поменять местами x и i:

```
Convert.ToDouble(Component.dataGridView1[i, x].Value)
```

Comment: глупая ситуация вышла, спасибо за ответ, буду делать перерывы в процессе написания ПО, а то еще алгоритм искусственного интеллекта напишется